# item is disappearing when pressed quickly. (framer motion)

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

the problem is in the mode="wait"
I don't know if its a bug or if it can even be solved but i hope someone can fix it
because its worse when navigating between pages

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState();

  const changeTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={changeTheme} className="pt-28">
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}>
        <motion.span
          initial={{
            opacity: 0,
            y: -20,
          }}
          animate={{
            y: 0,
            opacity: 1,
          }}
          exit={{
            opacity: 0,
            y: 20,
          }}
          transition={{
            type: "keyframes",
          }}
          key={theme}
        >
          {theme === "dark" ? <button>night</button> : <button>day</button>}
        </motion.span>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reprodicible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm not seeing the issue your described when testing in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/framer-motion-theme-switcher-animation-6t82x8?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx).